# show data in php

Tags: php, sql

I have two tables. `1.category` and `2.product`. In which I have one common `column` i.e. `categorycode`. In the `product` I inserted many products belonging to `category` but I want to show its `categoryname` in column corresponding to `categorycode`

Comment: Can you brief what you have tried yet ?

Comment: I really dont understand what to do

Comment: i am beginner..

Comment: Do you know about 'joins' in sql?

Comment: yup but not working

Comment: Show us your query and we might be able to help

Comment: $select="SELECT CategoryCode,CategoryName from tblcategorymaster WHERE tblcategorycode.CategoryCode=tblproductmaster.CategoryCode"; 
            echo $row['CategoryName'];

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1):

```
Select p.*, c.categoryname From product as p
Inner Join category as c ON c.categorycode = p.categorycode
```

Comment: $select_query1=$mysqli->query("Select p.*, c. From tblproductmaster as p Inner Join tblcategorymaster as c ON c.CategoryCode =p.CategoryCode;");
          if(mysqli_num_rows($select_query1)>0)
          {
           while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($select_query1))
           {
       
         <tr><td><?php echo $row['CategoryName']?></td>}

Comment: $select_query1=$mysqli->query("SELECT *,CategoryName From tblproductmaster INNER JOIN tblcategorymaster ON tblproductmaster.CategoryCode=tblcategorymaster.CategoryCode");

Comment: @NatashaTashu I miss `c.categoryname` from the first answer, Actually unless you provide us with your `schema` we will just try to guess :|

Comment: but using this nothing is displayed in table

Comment: i will give u description about my tables

Comment: How do you access your database ? By `phpMyAdmin` or some other `IDE`s ? @NatashaTashu

Comment: tblcategorycode-categoryid,categorycode,categoryname

Comment: tblproductmaster-productid,productcode,productname,categoryname

Comment: i just want to show categoryname in product table corresponding to categorycode

Comment: @NatashaTashu It's a bad schema, Sorry. I will provide you with another answer containing some description

Comment: sir i have another question from same tables

Answer (score 1):

This is the preferred schema for your case:

[image]

ANd now this is the create SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `tblcategorycode` (
  `categoryid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `categorycode` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `categoryname` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`categoryid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `categorycode_UNIQUE` (`categorycode`)
);

CREATE TABLE `tblproductmaster` (
  `productid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `productcode` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `productname` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `categoryid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`productid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `productcode_UNIQUE` (`productcode`),
  KEY `fkk_idx` (`categoryid`),
  CONSTRAINT `fkk` FOREIGN KEY (`categoryid`) REFERENCES `tblcategorycode` (`categoryid`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);
```

If you have like this schema then and with an easy Query like this:

```
SELECT p.*, c.categoryname
FROM test.tblproductmaster p
INNER JOIN tblcategorycode c ON p.categoryid = c.categoryid;
```

You will get what you want.

**But make sure that `categoryid` column is the linking part of your 2 tables, It must contains same value from the parent and child table**